# Send email with some [text] files with TIdPOP3Server

Tags: delphi, email, pop3, indy10

I have no problems sending a text file via the `OnRetrieve` event of `TIdPOP3Server` in indy 10, but I don't know how to send multiple files. I see with SMTP it is achieved with `TIdAttachment` to the `TIdMessage`, but how to send `TIdAttachment` from my `TIdPOP3Server.OnRetrieve` event to my POP3 client who can then read the sent files like this :

```
if MsgDecode.MessageParts[i] Is TIdAttachment then begin
  (MsgDecode.MessageParts[i] as TIdAttachment).SaveToFile((MsgDecode.MessageParts[j] as TIdAttachment).FileName);
```

Can anyone help me with this issue ?

This is my OnRetrieve event :

```
procedure POP3ServerRetrieve(aCmd: TIdCommand; AMsgNo: Integer); 
If (AMsgNO >= 1) AND (AMsgNo<=myMailsCount) then begin 
aCmd.SendReply; 
aCmd.Response.LoadFromFile('mail_filename'); 
aCmd.Response.LoadFromFile('mail_attachment_filename_1'); 
// ... loading N attachments 
end 
Else aCmd.Reply.SetReply(ERR,Format(' -Message %d Does not exist.',[AMsgNO]));
```

Comment: Please show your `OnRetreive` event handler code. Are you using `TIdMessage` to send the email to the client? `TIdMessage` works the same way in POP3 as it does in SMTP. If you are not using `TIdMessage` then you have to deal with MIME manually instead.

Comment: This is my OnRetrieve event :
procedure POP3ServerRetrieve(aCmd: TIdCommand; AMsgNo: Integer);
    If (AMsgNO >= 1) AND (AMsgNo<=myMailsCount) then begin
      aCmd.SendReply;
      aCmd.Response.LoadFromFile('mail_filename');
      aCmd.Response.LoadFromFile('mail_attachment_filename_1');
      // ... loading N attachments
    end
    Else
      aCmd.Reply.SetReply(ERR,Format(' -Message %d Does not exist.',[AMsgNO]));

Comment: @RemyLebeau,  can you give me an example how to send TIdMessage through TIdCommand (the first argument in the POP3ServerOnRetrieve event) ?

Comment: Please edit your question to add your code to it, do not put it in a comment.

Comment: You cannot call `Response.LoadFromFile()` to load multiple files. Each call wipes out the data from the previous call. Why are you not using `TIdMessage` to prepare the email?

Comment: @RemyLebeau You mean to create TIdMessage, add attachments to it and then execute TIdMessage.SaveToStream(myStream) and then do aCmd.Response.loadFromStream(myStream) ? - but I still can't make it work like this ...

Comment: `TIdMessage.SaveTo...()` formats the email with dot transparency enabled (a line beginning with a dot is escaped with an extra dot that the receiver removes), but `aCmd.Response` is also sent using dot transparency, so escaped lines would be escaped a second time. You do not want that. Instead of using `aCmd.Response.LoadFromStream(myStream)`, use `aCmd.Connection.IOHandler.Write(myStream)` instead since `myStream` is already in the correct format.

Comment: If you use `aCmd.Response` you have to use it before calling `aCmd.SendReply()`, not after. If you use `IOHandler.Write()`, call `aCmd.SendReply()` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
procedure POP3ServerRetrieve(aCmd: TIdCommand; AMsgNo: Integer); 
var
  Msg: TIdMessage;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  if (AMsgNO >= 1) AND (AMsgNo <= myMailsCount) then
  begin 
    Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      Msg := TIdMessage.Create;
      try
        // fill Msg as needed ...
        Msg.SaveToStream(Stream);
      finally
        Msg.Free;
      end;
      aCmd.Reply.SetReply(OK, 'message follows');
      aCmd.SendReply; 
      aCmd.Connection.IOHandler.Write(Stream);
    finally
      Stream.Free;
    end;
  end 
  else
    aCmd.Reply.SetReply(ERR, Format('Message %d Does not exist.', [AMsgNO])); 
end;
```